# php login script that also works on subdirectories?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2

I know it's quite easy to make a login script for one directory. However, how do you make it work recursively (subdirectories)?

Thanks!

Comment: By "login script" do you mean HTTP authentication? If that's the case, just take it out of any `<Directory></Directory>` tags and it should work in subdirectories.

Comment: Hi Henry, I don't like the default http authentication, therefore I'm looking for a solution in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go about this a couple different ways.

Your first option (and the most intuitive) is to simply include your authentication code (checking for session, etc.) in every page within the directory. This just means a lot of copy-pasting an `include()` statement.

However, if you're looking to protect non-script content like images or other files, you can use Apache's `mod_rewrite` to redirect any calls for files to a single PHP script that handles authentication. This is the more robust method and is widely used, but it has a small learning curve to work with `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Hi Henry, I'm looking for a mod_rewrite solution, can you direct me to a good example to start with? Thanks

Comment: @FLX, I like [this article](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) and its examples. When you write your rules, make sure that you capture the requested file in the regular expression and include it in the new URI. That way, your script can pull the requested filename from `$_GET[]`.

Comment: thanks, I've used that article in the past. However, the problem I have is that is infinite recursion as I do not know of a good way in php to pass-through if authentication succeeds. Currently it goes: request -> mod_rewrite -> php:authenticated!redirecting to page -> request -> mod_rewrite -> php:authenticated!redirecting to page -> request. ad infinitum, any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: @FLX, you might write your PHP script so it redirects to an internal URI that you rewrite using the `[L]` flag (for Last). That'll stop processing rewrites on that rule, but keep in mind that using `[L]` with `[R]` is ineffective.

Alternatively, you could serve the file directly from the PHP script. If done well, this means the process is completely transparent to the user and they never see an HTTP redirect on their end. This is the method I recommend. (It still uses `mod_rewrite` for the first step, of course.) Do you know what file types you'll be serving?

Comment: basically I'm hosting everything, from directories to script to images on a root server level, so nothing will be viewable until you logged in. Do you have a concrete example of how you would implement this? Thanks a lot!